# Was Niklas Luhmann critical of environmental movements?

Tags: social-sciences

A number of years ago, during the break at a social theory seminar, someone mentioned that Niklas Luhmann was highly critical of environmental movements. Since the seminar was more about systems theory than any dislikes of particular movements, I didn’t dig deeper into that claim. Now however, I would be most curious to find out if there are any evidence of Luhmann publicly criticizing environmental movements because I can’t find much in his writings that I have access to (e.g. *Social Systems*)?

Comment: Outside my area of expertise. Have you consulted *Ökologische Kommunikation,* Opladen: Westdeutscher Verlag 1986 (English translation: *Ecological Communication,* Chicago: University of Chicago Press 1990)?